# APT - Broken packages when trying to install Wine32

Tags: linux, debian, apt, dependencies, wine

I am trying to install wine32.

Running `sudo apt install wine32` returns the following output:

```
Reading package list... Done
Create dependency tree
Reading status information... Done

Some packages cannot be installed. This may mean that
asked for an impossible situation or, if you are using the distribution
unstable, that some required packages have not yet been created or are
have taken from «Incoming». The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 4.0-2) but will not install

E: Unable to fix problems, has saved broken packages.
```

I'm using huayra 5.0, in case it helps.

Comment: `dpkg --add-architecture i386` then `apt update`

Comment: Where is this wine32 package coming from?  It doesn't seem to be in either the i386 or amd64 Packages lists for main, contrib, or non-free on https://repo.huayra.educar.gob.ar/huayra/dists/5.0/  (I downloaded them all to check). Is it from some older Huayra release?   Have you added some other repo from another distro or a PPA? that typically causes more problems (bugs, incompatibilities, general brokenness) than it solves (impatience).    BTW, wine 4.0 is getting pretty old now, it was released in 2019.  Current stable release is wine 7.0

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm a you have added the `i386` architecture (`dpkg --add-architecture i386`), as Huayra 5 only has an `amd64` version.

As cas said in the comments, `wine32` is not in Huayra's repo.
I would try to install Wine32 from WineHQ's repo.
To do this, first of all you will need to download and add WineHQ's repository key.

```
sudo mkdir -pm755 /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
```

Then download the sources file for the corresponding Debian version (Huayra 5 is based off Debian Buster. For future reference, if you're using another version of Debian change `buster` with your Debian version codename)

```
sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/dists/buster/winehq-buster.sources
```

Once this is done, you will need to update the package lists: `sudo apt update`

And finally, to install Wine32 run:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends wine32
```